# How to remove duplicate entries in postgresql table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `postgresql` table without primary key.
I want to remove all entries that have the same id, but retain the most recent one.

The following statement almost works:

```
DELETE FROM mytable USING mytable t
  WHERE mytable.id = t.id AND mytable.modification < t.modification;
```

Problem: when two entries have the same modification timestamp (which is possible), both are retained.
What would I have to change to just keep one of them, does not matter which one?

I cannot change the condition to `AND mytable.modification <= t.modification;` as this would then remove all dublicates not retaining any entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have rows that are complete duplicates (i.e., no way to distinguish one from the other), then you have two options.  One is to use a built-in row identifier such as `ctid`:

```
DELETE FROM mytable USING mytable t
  WHERE mytable.id = t.id AND
        (mytable.modification < t.modification OR
         mytable.modification = t.modification AND mytable.ctid < t.ctid);
```

Or use a secondary table:

```
create table tokeep as
    select distinct on (t.id) t.*
    from mytable
    order by t.id, t.modification;

truncate table mytable;

insert into mytable
    select * from tokeep;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use EXISTS to see if there are other rows with same id:

```
DELETE FROM mytable t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from mytable
              WHERE id = t.id AND modification > t.modification);
```

Comment: I tried it but 0 rows where affected in a table with 2 entries having exactly the same id and modification timestamp. But one of them should get deleted.

Comment: It's hard to remove just one of two equal rows. Move to temp-table using select distinct?

Comment: Could I tell the `select distinct(id)` to fetch the most recent row with the latest modification stamp?

Comment: See Gordon Linoff's answer above.